# Cypress JS and ability to upload and append an image

Tags: javascript, cypress

So I'm working on uploading a file in Cypress. Now I have an issue of appending the image to the page. I'm trying to upload/append the image under the following:

```
<label for="upload-137" class="field-upload>
 <div class="layout justify-center">
  <span class="v-btn">
   <div class="v-btn__content">
    <i class="v-icon">add</i>
   </div>
  </span>
 </div>
 <input id="upload-137" name="upload" type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" class="file-input">
</label>
```

Specifically I'm looking to append it after layout as a sibling after the span.

So my thought would be:

```
   cy.fixture('/driver/jack.jpg', 'base64').then(fileContent => {
    const jack = cy.get('input[type="file"]').upload({
      fileContent,
      fileName: 'jack.jpg',
      mimeType: 'image/jpg'
    }, {
      subjectType: 'input'
    }, );
    cy.get('.field-upload > .layout').then(($div) => {
      function words(){
        var image = document.createElement("img");
        image.setAttribute("src", jack);
        var location = document.getElementsByClassName("layout");
        location.appendChild(image);
      }
      $div.append(words)
    })
  })
```

My thinking was to use cypress upload package to pull in the file to assign it to the input field and upload. Then get the location, create the img, set the source including in the fixture that's been uploaded. Then append it to the location (based on class name).

I end up getting

> TypeError: location.appendChild is not a function

Is there a way to append an image that was uploaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues with the code:

1. `document` in your test code will refer to the `document` being used to run your tests, you actually want to use [`cy.document()`](https://on.cypress.io/document) to obtain the document of the application under test (AUT)
2. `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of `HTMLElement`s, so you'd need to get the first element from that array to use it.

The corrected code would look like this:

```js
cy.fixture('/driver/jack.jpg', 'base64').then(fileContent => {
  cy.get('input[type="file"]').upload({
    fileContent,
    fileName: 'jack.jpg',
    mimeType: 'image/jpg'
  }, {
    subjectType: 'input'
  }, );

  cy.document().then($document => {
    cy.get('.field-upload > .layout').then(($div) => {
      function words(){
        var image = $document.createElement("img");
        image.setAttribute("src", "path/to/jack.jpg");
        return image
      }
      $div.append(words)
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The method [document.getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns you an array of elements. Where as [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) is a method of an element. Hence you are getting the error.

To resolve this, there are 2 ways,

1. **Assign ID**

Assign an ID to your HTML element which makes it unique and get this element via [document.getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById). After that you can append your other element to it.

```
<label for="upload-137" class="field-upload>
 <div class="layout justify-center" id="layoutContainer">
  <span class="v-btn">
   <div class="v-btn__content">
    <i class="v-icon">add</i>
   </div>
  </span>
 </div>
 <input id="upload-137" name="upload" type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" class="file-input">
</label>
```

And in your JavaScript:

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.setAttribute("src", jack);
var location = document.getElementById("layoutContainer");
location.appendChild(image);
```

**2. Get element from array**

If you do not ant to assign an ID, you can get the element from the array via index. Although in this case, you need to be sure that there is only one HTML tag with the class `layout`.

```
var image = document.createElement("img");
image.setAttribute("src", jack);
var location = document.getElementsByClassName("layout")[0];
location.appendChild(image);
```